# how to set-up default value of variable inside of object in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have this schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  itemDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  itemName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  itemPrice: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,

    price: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
      default: 'USD',
    },
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', schema)
```

and using this mutation for adding item:

```
  Mutation: {
    addItem: async (_, args) => {
      const { itemName, itemPrice } = args.itemInput
      let { itemDate } = args

      if (!itemDate) {
        itemDate = new Date()
      }
      const item = new Item({ itemDate, itemName, itemPrice })
      await item.save()
      return item
    },
```

However when adding item, the currency remains null, what am I missing here?
I can add the currency in the addItem mutation:

```
itemPrice.currency = 'USD'
```

however there must be a better way, isn't that so?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `args`

Comment: args :>>  {
  itemInput: {
    itemDate: '1.1.2022',
    itemName: 'item1',
    itemPrice: { price: '199', currency: 'USD' }
  }
}